# create an output column

Tags: sql, database, datagrid, report, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working on a customer level, and I have a column that contains the 3 types of products I'm selling, what I want is to know every customer what products they already purchased?
but what if that customer has purchased more than one item?
I want to create a column that tell me what they exactly bought 'Coffee','mug' or 'chocolate'..
how can I represent that in the output? again, all these info are stored in one column called 'product'

Thank you

Comment: Hello. Firstly I'd like to mention, that Stackoverflow is not a homework writing service. That being said, we'll need you to provide more information: Your tables, your data, your current work and your current as well as desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use GROUP_CONCAT (mySQL) or STRING_AGG (tSQL)

So you want to do something like this for mysql:

```
SELECT a.[CustomerID], GROUP_CONCAT(a.[Product])  as Products 
FROM [tblSells] a 
GROUP BY a.[CustomerID];
```

Or something like this for tsql:

```
SELECT a.[CustomerID], STRING_AGG(a.[Product],'.') as Products 
FROM [tblSells] a
GROUP BY a.[CustomerID];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Snowflake, you can use `LISTAGG` or `ARRAY_AGG` depending on whether you want to store the data as a string or as an array.  In Snowflake, I would recommend that you store this data as an array, as it is easier to deal with when querying later.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html